# 1950s TV show called Captain 'something'. One of his crew was named Astro

Tags: story-identification, aliens, history-of

I'm looking for the name of a program that appeared on TV around 1952-53 in Pittsburgh. Pennsylvania. There was a new (the first I think) educational TV channel; 13, KQED or WQED maybe. They had a space show. I thought it might be one of several shows named captain something. I checked those out and it wasn't. One of the characters was named Astro. He was from another planet. I think he bounced from crew to crew cause he was always mouthing off. Anyway, I recall an episode where he was kvetching because he thought Earth's air stank.

Comment: You've tagged this question "aliens". Were there aliens?

Comment: As I said Astro's character was not of the Earth. Thanks for your edit (zero?) But that will confuse the response to my question. in my research I viewed on u tube Captain Zero episodes. He's not the one, he zips around Earth sub space in what looks like a model of the Bell X5. The space crew of the show I remember were always in the control deck of a space ship. I won't remove your edit out of my respect for your rank. But you might.

Comment: Should I take from this experience and the extensive edit of myoriginal question body that there is no room for humor in science friction? Nobody slapped Han Solo's hand when he called Princess Leah -Your Warship.

Comment: If people can't work out what you're asking, your question is essentially useless, regardless of how funny you might think it is

Comment: If you have an edit that would improve the question, use the [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/175006/edit) button.

Comment: I love science fiction and I have learned much in my few days here.  But I might consider moving to a playground with a little more levity. I'm willing to risk getting bumped at this point. But as a friend of mine who's also uses this site said "these guys take themselves pretty seriously. So I might not be a good fit. No where on this site is there a rule that says no humor- no fun.

Comment: [Stack Exchange: Where we Hate Fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). In short it's perfectly ok to [have a bit of fun](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102822/could-i-fake-death-to-stop-being-force-choked), but not at the expense of actually posting an answerable question or a sensible answer.

Comment: See also [The Illusion of Transparency](http://lesswrong.com/lw/ke/illusion_of_transparency_why_no_one_understands/).

Comment: Harry, do you remember in Happy Days how hard it was for the Fonz to say the word love---he would go lllll-lll-ll-llllllll. He just couldn't 't do it. So I just -lll-lll-ll-- llllllearned something. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [Tom Corbett, Space Cadet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Corbett,_Space_Cadet). It was shown in the 1950s, featured a captain named "***Captain Strong***" and a Venusian character named Astro who didn't like Earth very much.

Comment: Valorum that's it. Well done. Maybe I'm the Astro here.

Comment: My father had a homemade Tom Corbett costume.

Comment: I'm sure I saw my costume around here just a few minutes ago----

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Captain Z-Ro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Z-Ro) from 1955?

> Scientist Captain Z-Ro, working in his remote laboratory, safeguarded
>   mankind and history from impending harm. He had a time machine, the
>   ZX-99, both to view history and to send someone back in time. Each
>   week, he and his teenage assistant Jet would view an episode in time
>   and inevitably see that some event was unfolding contrary to history
>   (e.g., King John not signing the Magna Carta). Captain Z-Ro would then
>   send Jet back in time to intervene and ensure that history played out
>   as originally recorded.

Comment: No I already checked this one out. But You nailed it on your first answer. I didn't see your answered come in until just a few minutes ago. I don't understand the time shift between comments showing up faster than answers. That would have changed mi dialogue with you. I'm going to brew another cup of coffee. Ciao

Comment: @eric the time shift is an unfortunate side effect of Jet interfering with the time stream.  Later generations know this as "a glitch in the matrix"  Carry on with your coffee, nothing to see here.